# Prove that $f$ is bounded and uniformly continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and suppose that there exists a number
$P > 0$ such that $$f (x + P ) = f (x)$$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Prove that the function is bounded and uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

I'm not sure what to do.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: *Hint:* Notice that the the image of $f$, $f(\mathbb R)$ is given entirely by the image of the interval $[0,P]$. That is, $f(\mathbb R) = f([0,P])$. Given that, what can you say about $f$?

Comment: Hint: $[0,P] $ is compact and contains all "information" about  $f $.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Take $x_0,x_1  \in [0,P]$ and notice that $f|_{[0.P]}$ attains to its maximum and minimum . [Extreme Value Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem).

What happens to a continuous function on a compact set?